# Installing GeoIP - maxminddb_module and libmaxminddb Errors

Tags: geoip

After installing maxminddb_module and libmaxminddb from

http://maxmind.github.io/mod_maxminddb/   and
https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb

On restarting apache, I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 243 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_maxminddb.so into server: libmaxminddb.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

httpd.conf line 243 is:

```
LoadModule maxminddb_module   /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_maxminddb.so
```

It seems everything is in its right place, but I can't get them all to play nice and talk to each other.  Would appreciate some assistance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

From https://github.com/maxmind/libmaxminddb :

If after installing, you receive an error that `libmaxminddb.so.0` is missing you may need to add the lib directory in your prefix to your library path. On most Linux distributions when using the default prefix (`/usr/local`), you can do this by running the following commands:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo /usr/local/lib  >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/local.conf"
$ ldconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo ldconfig` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Have tried that, to no effect.  Is there a way to effectively and completely uninstall both of them and then try again from a blank slate?